# How to resolve Mosquitto bridge protocol error

Tags: azure-iot-hub, mosquitto

I have installed Mosquitto on Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to connect to Azure IoT Hub. Below is the content of `mosquitto.con`:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Below is the `bridge.conf` file

```
connection iothub-bridge
log_type all
address ripe.azure-devices.net:8883
remote_username ripe.azure-devices.net/ripe001
remote_password SharedAccessSignature sr=ripe.azure-devices.net&sig=C5t0H%2F3eCS47Xnf38s%3D&se=253402297199.516&skn=iothubowner
remote_clientid ripe001
bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
try_private false
cleansession false
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1.2
notifications false
#notification_topic events/

#cleansession false
#persistence true
#max_queued_messages 0
keepalive_interval 36000
autosave_interval 30

topic # out 2 devices/ripe001/messages/events/ devices/ripe001/messages/events/
topic # in 2 devices/ripe001/messages/devicebound/ devices/ripe001/messages/devicebound/
```

The Mosquitto service is running fine but in logs I can see protocol error.

```
1650357942: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1650357942: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1650357942: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1650357942: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1650357942: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1650357942: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1650357942: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1650357942: Bridge local.ripe001 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/ripe001/messages/events/#
1650357942: Connecting bridge (step 1) iothub-bridge (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1650357942: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1650357942: Connecting bridge (step 2) iothub-bridge (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1650357942: Bridge ripe001 sending CONNECT
1650357942: Client local.ripe001 disconnected: Protocol error.
```

Mosquitto version:

```
mosquitto version 2.0.14

mosquitto is an MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.

Usage: mosquitto [-c config_file] [-d] [-h] [-p port]

 -c : specify the broker config file.
 -d : put the broker into the background after starting.
 -h : display this help.
 -p : start the broker listening on the specified port.
      Not recommended in conjunction with the -c option.
 -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
      any logging options given in the config file.

See https://mosquitto.org/ for more information.
```

I have even tried changing the `tls_version` from `1.2` to `1.3` but it didn't help. Why am I getting a protocol error?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Azure IoT Hub as a device? If so, the value for remote_password is wrong, it seems to be using a Service SDK key instead of the device one.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer For password, I am using the SAS token which I believe is correct other wise  mosquitto logs says authorization error. For this question, I have removed some part of the token

Comment: Your token contains `&skn=iothubowner` which means you're using a SAS token on behalf of the iothubowner policy instead of connecting as a device. Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device) for the token structure you need. The username field also seems incorrect, Microsoft recommends including the API version (that could be the cause of your protocol issue).

Comment: Also you can explicitly set theo MQTT protocol version for the bridge with `bridge_protocol_version`

Comment: @hardillb sorry didnt get you, am I using incorrect version?. Which version I should use? As  I am using `mqttv311`

Comment: Sorry, my fault I missed that you already had that in the config

Comment: @hardillb I have tested everything in office and with same version and same config its working in office but not on client site. It looks like clients network is blocking some thing. Is there anyway I can test what is getting blocked

Comment: [Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1021) and [Mosquitto SSL protocol error after upgrading to 2.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/1075259/mosquitto-ssl-protocol-error-after-upgrading-to-2-0t)

Answer (score 0):

The default version of MQTT will be 3.1

Add the `bridge_protocolo_version` option to the config and it accepts `mqttv31` and `mqttv311`

```
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
```

Note:

***Disable privilege bridge extension.***

```
try_private false
```